# Input a number, Search through Lists and Dictionary, print associated key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am having an issue pulling from a combined dictionary and list. I understand how to pull keys from each one individually but I need to combine them and pull the keys from both. The following is an Example of a dictionary listing years. Each year has a title and director associated with it.

```
movie_collection = {
    2005: {'Title':'Munich','Director':'Steven Spielberg'},
    2005: {'Title':'The Prestige','Director':'Christopher Nolan'},
    2006: {'Title':'The Departed','Director':'Martin Scorsese'},
    2007: {'Title':'Into the Wild','Director':'Sean Penn'},
    2008: {'Title':'The Dark Knight','Director':'Christopher Nolan'},
    2009: {'Title':'Mary and Max','Director':'Adam Elliot'},
    2010: {'Title':'The King''s Speech','Director':'Tom Hooper'},
    2011: {'Title':'The Artist','Director':'Michel Hazanavicius'},
    2011: {'Title':'The Help','Director':'Tate Taylor'},
    2012: {'Title':'Argo','Director':'Ben Affleck'},
    2013: {'Title':'12 Years a Slave','Director':'Steve McQueen'},
    2014: {'Title':'Birdman','Director':'Alejandro G. Inarritu'},
    2015: {'Title':'Spotlight','Director':'Tom McCarthy'},
    2016: {'Title':'The BFG','Director':'Steven Spielberg'}
```

}

I also have the code prompting for an input year between 2005 and 2016. If the year is not between those years it will print a N/A.

```
input_year = int(input('Enter a year between 2005 and 2016:\n'))
if input_year < 2005:
    print('N/A')
elif input_year > 2016:
    print('N/A')
else:
    print(input_year)
```

Now here is where I am having an issue. Right after the else statment, I need to also print the title and director of the movies associated with the input year. Example if you input the year 2011 the output needs to be:

Enter a year between 2005 and 2016:
2011
The Artist, Michel Hazanavicius
The Help, Tate Taylor

I have the following code written.

```
if input_year in movie_collection:
    for Title,Director in movie_collection.values():
        print(Title,',',Director)
```

But it does not output the correct information.

```
Enter a year between 2005 and 2016:
2011
Director , Title
Director , Title
Director , Title
Director , Title
...
```

I have tried listing it multiply ways but it sill not pull the information correctly. I am still new to python and I did try google and bing with no luck on the information I seek. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Have I written the dictionary incorrectly? Or am I just not using the correct way to print the information.Thanks

Comment: Something like `if year in movie_collection: print(movie_collection[year]['Title'], movie_collection[year]['Director'])`.  You should note that no two `movie_collection` entries can share the same year (key).  Instead, the latermost will overwrite all the previous entries.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick for the quick response.  I have fiddled with your suggested code and it worked perfectly except for the part about "no two movie_collection entries can share the same year (key)." I actually didn't even think of this since the instructions said to list it by year and combine Title and Director into a list. Any suggestions on how I can recode that to still follow the year input format and keep "Title and Director" as a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stay with your data structure, modify the listing code like so:

```
if input_year in movie_collection:
    movies_for_year = movie_collection[input_year]
    print(movies_for_year['Title'], ',', movies_for_year['Director'])
```

However, this will not give you what you want since, as mentioned in the comments the duplicate year keys overwrite each other - test this with:

```
print(movie_collection)
```

1: Depending on whether you always access the movies year first, or by any other attribute, use a list instead of a dicts with the year attribute as part of the movie:

```
movie_collection = [
 {'Year':2005, 'Title':'Munich','Director':'Steven Spielberg'},
 {'Year':2005, 'Title':'The Prestige','Director':'Christopher Nolan'},
 #.... rest of list here
 {'Year':2016, 'Title':'The BFG','Director':'Steven Spielberg'}
 ]
```

The output code would read like so:

```
for movie in movie_collection:
    if movie.get('Year', -1) == input_year:
        print(movie.get('Title', 'NA'), ',', movie.get('Director', 'NA'))
```

2: To maintain your by year index, the datastructue would be a dict of lists, which looks like:

```
movie_collection = {
 2005: [{'Title':'Munich'},
        {'Title':'The Prestige','Director':'Christopher Nolan'}],
 #.... rest of list here
 2016: [{'Title':'The BFG','Director':'Steven Spielberg'}]
}
```

and the output code becomes:

```
for movie in movie_collection.get(input_year, []):
    print(movie.get('Title', 'NA'), ',', movie.get('Director', 'NA'))
```

A small note, I am using dict.get instead of slicing because if a movie entity is missing an attribute, or in second case if year has no movies this will return the safe provided default instead of crashing - this also reduces the amount of 'if thing in dict' code. If you are 100% sure the keys exist, you can slice, but be warned! see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict for more info on this.

cheers

Answer (score 0):

```
year_input = input("Enter the year\n")
if year_input < str(2005):
    print('N/A')
elif year_input > str(2016):
    print('N/A')
else:
    print(movie_collection[str(year_input)]['Title'], ',', movie_collection[str(year_input)]['Director'])
```

As the keys are years which are integers we need to convert to string. So I converted using str() at the last line.

Comment: As the keys are years which are integers we need to convert to string. So  converted using str() at the line "print(movie_collection[str(year_input)]['Title'], ',', movie_collection[str(year_input)]['Director'])"